# Comparing a NotesDateTime in JAVA

Tags: java, date, comparison, xpages

Notes really does not like blank(null) dates and has caused me no end of grief. So in native Notes applications I have assigned all date fields a value of GMT 01/10/1970 0:0:0 AM

then at time to display the date if it equals the GMT time I display "-" as a place holder in multi-value fields. I'm want to create a little JAVA method that compares a date passed to the GMT date and if the same return true else return false. I think I'm OK with the code to the point that I have below, but now I'm not sure how to compare dt (converted to GMT ) to GMT the simple = does not appear to work so I suspect I have some kind of comparison conflict. Any pointer in the right direction appreciated. I googled this but could not find a direct answer.

```
public static Boolean isBlankDate(Date dt){
        Boolean rtn = false;
        Session s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
        try{
            Date GMT = s.createDateTime("01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT").toJavaDate();
        }catch(NotesException e){
            System.out.println("Date Create Error " + e.toString());
            if (dt = GMT){
                rtn = true;
            }else{
                rtn = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
        //compare dt to GMT and if equal return true else false
        return rtn;
    }
```

Comment: honestly, bad idea... instead of null checks you need to compare to some magic constant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)

Comment: @Frantisek: the magic constant Bill uses is 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT. This constant is kind of "magic" as Java class Date represents this date as "0 milliseconds" from 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT. See my answer for more explanations on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if a native Notes data field contains 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT what you interpret as blank (null) data value. I assume you read the data value from document, convert the value to Java Date with `.toJavaDate()` and then want to test if it is 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT with your method `isBlankDate(Date dt)`.

If that is what you want to achieve then you can reduce your method to just

```
public static boolean isBlankDate(Date dt) {
    return dt.getTime() == 0;
}
```

`.getTime()` returns the number of milliseconds *since* January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by the Date object.

It returns `0` if Date is *exactly* 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT. So, the only thing you need to do is to test

```
dt.getTime() == 0
```

It returns *true*, if Date dt is 01/01/1970 0:0:0 AM GMT and returns *false* if not.

Comment: as usual great simple answer. We picked the date because it was zero date time, and this just makes things that much simpler. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

In Java you can compare Dates by firstDate.before(otherDate) or firstDate.after(otherDate) it will return a boolean

Comment: It's what I use for DateTime.isBefore(DateTime) and DateTime.isAfter(DateTime) in OpenNTF Domino API.

Comment: the dt object will be in local time and GMT will be GMT time - does the before and after and equals take care of that? When I do dt.equals(GMT) I get the error that GMT can not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking at comparing dates, `isBefore` / `isAfter` in java.util.Date class is useful. java.sql.Date allows you to create a Date as opposed to a DateTime.

[java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) is what I usually use for date manipulation / comparison in my own code. The Java APIs state that [java.util.Date](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) is deprecated in favour of it. You can pass in a java.util.Date using `setTime`. java.util.Calendar also has locales and timezones. It also has before and after methods.

Joda is a heavily used Java date/time API, but it doesn't come included in the Domino server.

Comment: And Calendar Object has timezone support

Answer (score 1):

"Notes really does not like blank(null) dates and has caused me no end of grief."

Actually that's not true. If you call both .setAnyTime() and .setAnyDate() you can still save as a DateTime but without any specific value.

Comment: This might be a bit inconvenient in Java context as `dateTime.setAnyDate(); dateTime.setAnyTime(); Date date = dateTime.toJavaDate();` throws a NotesException at .toJavaDate().